# Excel VBA - Можно ли скрыть таблицу на листе, не влияя на ячейки вокруг

Tags: excel, vba

Т.е. могу ли я скрыть ячейки `B2:D4` так, чтобы ячейки `B1,C1,D1,A2,A3,A4` остались видны.
Т.е. мне нужно скрыть `B2:D4`, но так, чтобы это не повлияло на размер, видимость, внешний вид окружающих их ячеейк по вертикали или горизонтали.

Я знаю, звучит немного не так, как таблицы работают, тем не менее.

Суть, на самом деле в том, что у меня есть несколько листов, и на одном из них мне нужно добавлять элементы управления (выпадающие списки, в основном) при нажатии на кнопку 'Добавить'.
Можно делать это динамически, но это связано с кучей макросов и на эти ячейки ссылаются поля на итоговом листе. Причем при добавлении элементов управления, мне нужно также 'добавлять' поля на итоговый лист. При этом под полями на итоговом листе (а еще слева и справа) есть еще другие заполненные ячейки.
Поэтому мне в голову пришла идея: добавить это все сразу, но для начала скрыть, чтобы потом показывать по мере надобности.
Если есть решение получше, с удовольствием приму.

Answer (score 1):

Так не получится. возьмите листик в клеточку и попробуйте спрятать такой диапазон.

Идея изначально неправильна. Нужно менять подход.

> это связано с кучей макросов и на эти ячейки ссылаются поля на итоговом листе.

Если используется VBA, можно вообще исключить ссылки в ячейках, считая все в коде или испоользуя события листа.

Можно обходным путем: значения в диапазоне временно не отображать, закрывать каким-либо объектом... Но это - костыли. Правильнее - решать задачу правильнее )